# Droplink value is always returning null in post action

Tags: glass-mapper, sitecore-api, links

I am trying to build a form which contains state as droplink and given datasource as states [image].

here's the snippets of my employee model and state.

[image]

[image]

i am getting all the states in the get action of form and passing them.

```
public ActionResult EmployeeForm()
    {
        var sitecoreService = new SitecoreService("master");
        var statesFolder = sitecoreService.GetItem<States>("/sitecore/content/Global/States", x => x.LazyDisabled());
        ViewBag.States  = statesFolder.Children;   
        return View();
    }
```

when i am trying to retreive the values then the state is mapped correctly but in the post action of form it is null.

here's the snippet of my form's state

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.State, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.State, new SelectList(ViewBag.States,"Id","Name"), "select a state", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.State, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Post action code:

```
 public ActionResult CreateItem(EmployeeModel employeeModel)
    {
        ID id = new ID("{529829D4-9DE6-4E30-AF40-D67EA93D3271}");
        var sitecoreService = new SitecoreService("master");
        var parent = sitecoreService.GetItem<Employees>(id.Guid);
        employeeModel.Name = "employee-" + employeeModel.EmployeeId;
        sitecoreService.CreateItem(parent, employeeModel);
        return View("~/Views/ContactBook/Success.cshtml", employeeModel);                  
    }
```

Comment: And what is your post action code?

Comment: Added the post action to the question @MarekMusielak

Comment: So you're sending a state ID from your form in a POST action and expect that glass will autopopulate the employeeModel with a State object? Can you try to change the `state` in `EmployeeModel` to string or ID and see if it's passed properly via the POST action? I don't think Glass will populate your objects in POST actions.

Comment: Changing the state to guid done the trick. Thanks a lot @MarekMusielak

Comment: Comments converted into an answer

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, you're sending a state ID from your form in a POST action back to the server. Your model contains `State` property, but it's an object of `State` class. It's not possible to populate object from ID in a POST action automatically OOTB.

What you should do instead is to change the type of `State` property in `EmployeeModel` class to `Guid` or `string` (and maybe call it `StateId`) and then retrieve the item from database:

```
public class EmployeeModel : DepartmentModel
{
    public Guid StateId { get; set }
    // ... other properties
}
```